# Get commit status in a GitHub action workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that is triggered on pull_request_review. I also have a commit status that’s updated by our CI system. Is there a way I can access the status of a commit directly in my workflow file? Thanks.

```
name: Verify on approval
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  ci_verify_job:
    if: {specific commit status == success}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: ci verify job
    steps:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
github.event.state == 'success'
```